# Create a for loop with different variables

Tags: r, for-loop

Probably a very easy question for those used to making "for" loops. Here is what I am trying to do using a loop (with AA being a matrix):

```
lines(x = c(AAx[1:2,1]), y = c(AAx[1:2,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[3:4,1]), y = c(AAx[3:4,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[5:6,1]), y = c(AAx[5:6,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[7:8,1]), y = c(AAx[7:8,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[9:10,1]), y = c(AAx[9:10,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[11:12,1]), y = c(AAx[11:12,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[13:14,1]), y = c(AAx[13:14,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[15:16,1]), y = c(AAx[15:16,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[17:18,1]), y = c(AAx[17:18,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[19:20,1]), y = c(AAx[19:20,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[21:22,1]), y = c(AAx[21:22,2]))
lines(x = c(AAx[23:24,1]), y = c(AAx[23:24,2]))
```

I tried:

```
i <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23)
j <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24)

for (i in i){
  for (j in j){
    lines(x = c(AAx[i:j,1]), y = c(AAx[i:j,2]))
  }
}
```

But without success. I'm sure there is an easy way but cannot figure it out for now. Any help appreciated.

I have a second but similar problem:

```
text(AAx[1,1],AAx[1,2], names[1], pos = 3)
text(AAx[3,1],AAx[3,2], names[2], pos = 3)
text(AAx[5,1],AAx[5,2], names[3], pos = 3)
text(AAx[7,1],AAx[7,2], names[4], pos = 3)
text(AAx[9,1],AAx[9,2], names[5], pos = 3)
text(AAx[11,1],AAx[11,2], names[6], pos = 3)
text(AAx[13,1],AAx[13,2], names[7], pos = 3)
text(AAx[15,1],AAx[15,2], names[8], pos = 3)
text(AAx[17,1],AAx[17,2], names[9], pos = 3)
text(AAx[19,1],AAx[19,2], names[10], pos = 3)
text(AAx[21,1],AAx[21,2], names[11], pos = 3)
text(AAx[23,1],AAx[23,2], names[12], pos = 3)

names <-  c(“AA”,”BB”,”CC”,”DD”,”EE”,”FF”,”GG”,”HH”,”EE”,”JJ”,”KK”,”LL”)
j <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23)
```

I tried:

```
for (i in j){
  for (k in 1:length(names)){
    text(AAx[i,1],AAx[i,2], names[k], pos = 3)
    }
  }
```

I received helpful answer from the first problem but I am still stuck with the second one. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `AAx[i:(i+1),...]` or `AAx[c(i,i+1),...]`

Comment: No need to nest it `for(i in seq(1, 23, by=2) {; lines(x=AAx[i:(i+1), 1], y=AAx[i:(i+1), 2]); };` should do it.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want lines() to do. Is this a method you are invoking with the parameters x and y, where x and y are lists?

Comment: Thanks! That was much simpler than what I was trying to do. Can't believe I did not see that...!

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
j <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23)
k <- 1

for (i in j){
  lines(x = c(AAx[i:(i+1),1]), y = c(AAx[i:(i+1),2]))
  text(AAx[i,1],AAx[i,2], names[k], pos = 3)
  k <- k+1
}
```